# DI Container and the tailored MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I have build a in-house MVC PHP framework and now I am struggling on implementing DI Container. I've adopted the Pimple as a DiC, I have read the book by Chris Hartjes *"[The Grumpy Programmer's Guide To Building Testable PHP Applications](https://leanpub.com/grumpy-testing)"* (which I find a very good and inspiring read, will recommend it highly!), which talks eased me to understand more about TDD. Anyway, If I get a DI in the core of the framework, how should I populate the definitions and ho should I pass it along.

1. Injecting the container(Injecting in the application object all the way to the user created controller). - **WRONG**
2. Forcing the dev-user to 'populate' it in the Bootstrap - **WRONG**
3. Singleton - **VERY WRONG**
4. Observer Pattern (DiC attached to the observer. Observer as a front end to DiC) - **?(Probably the worst idea :D )**

Then how to make the core DiC available in the whole framework (for, lets say, injecting the Configuration Object), without creating any dependencies, unnecessary forcing the user to code it or adding the overhead of creating XML/JSON or any other.

PS:
** I do believe that I will see a lot of answers about the Inversion-of-Control (IoC) and Service Locator. Which I cant seem to get exactly how to implement them.. Reference me to a simple/basic guide.

Comment: Pimple is a service locator (glorified registry) and **not** a DI container. Also, you do not need DI container to use dependency injection in your code.

Comment: I got confused, everywhere I read (even the main site) says it is a Simple DiC, could you evaluate?

Comment: DI container lets you assemble the responsibilities of the class that need to be injected in the constructor. It will either perform the complete assembly or just provide the list of dependencies associated to a class. DI containers in general reside within factories/builders. A service locator is a dependency of a class, which an instance will then use *pull in* dependencies that it really needs.

Comment: Well if a DI container is to reside(be accessible from) inside the factory, this means that it creates a dependency between the factory and the container? or I am missing something here

Comment: What's stopping you from `$myFactory = new FooFactory( new DIContainer );`. I hope that, when you hear "factory", you do not associate with "static factory method", because the latter IMHO is quite a bad practice.

Comment: I do understand the factory pattern, but what I have been reading these days, was that injecting the DI container is not a good idea that is what I referred to by point 1.? If you could form a simple answer summarizing the comments you gave and explain a little bit more, I do believe that this could be of help to someone.

Comment: Your "point nr.1" talks about injecting the DI Container in the instance. That results in class pulling in responsibilities from outside of it. The factory is creating the instance. Factory can depend on DI container, because it's providing the factory with parts for assembling said instance. Ehh ... I guess I will have to write a real answer. It just take too much time to write 'em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(disclaimer, I'm the developer of [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/))

I don't really understand your question, it seems to me that if you have full control over the MVC framework, then using DI and a DIC should be pretty easy. Here is a copy of the introduction to DI on PHP-DI homepage:

> - Application needs FooController so:
> - Application gets FooController from the Container, so:
>
>   - Container creates SomeRepository
>   - Container creates BarService and gives it SomeRepository
>   - Container creates FooController and gives it BarService
> - Application calls FooController
>
>   - FooController calls BarService
>
>     - BarService calls SomeDependency
>
>       - SomeRepository does something

The Container is in charge of creating all the objects (the object graph), and then the non-framework code (controllers, services, …) works without **EVER** calling the Container.

> Then how to make the core DiC available in the whole framework?

Do not make it available in the whole framework.

Each component (object) should have its dependencies injected (for example in the constructor). The container will inject them (because the container creates all the objects), and the container should be called **at the root of your application** (the front controller).

---

Example: you want to inject the Configuration object in a controller:

```
class MyController {
    private $configuration;

    public function __construct(Configuration $configuration) {
        $this->configuration = $configuration;
    }
}
```

Since that the role of the DIC to create that controller, it will inject the configuration object.

Also, I don't think you should inject the whole configuration object, but just the values you are interested in (but that's another debate).

And also, if you have questions about how to write your controllers, maybe you should read this: [Controllers as services?](http://mnapoli.fr/controllers-as-services/).